# Quiero hacer un if anidado en Crystal reports

Tags: condiciones, crystal-reports

estoy haciendo un reporte en crystal reports en la versión del producto 11, quiero hacer un if para saber de donde provienen unas cancelaciones ya que manejo dos tablas llamadas Datos e Historial, despues de cierto tiempo las cancelaciones pasan a la tabla Historial, en el reporte cree una formula llamada "Prueba" que al arrastrar ese campo cuando aparezca la cancelación me aparezca una D si viene de la tabla datos o una H si es de la tabla historial, cabe mencionar que no se mucho de la syntaxis de crystal reports, he estado investigando pero no le encuentro solución.
Este es el código que estoy usando pero me marca error en los ultimos dos End If mencionando que el texto no parece ser parte de la formula.

```
If {SPCANCELACIONES;1.STATUSDA} = "C" Then
    If InStr({SPCANCELACIONES;1.NUMRESDA}, "H_") > 0 Then
        "Historial"
    Else
        "Datos"
    End If
End If
```